# How to solve the error "Species labels in 'x' and 'a' need to be identical and ordered alphabetically (or simply in the same order)" in R?

Tags: r, matrix, error-handling

I want to compute the CWM (community weighted mean) with the function "functcomp", but I always have the same error which is "Species labels in 'x' and 'a' need to be identical and ordered alphabetically (or simply in the same order)".

Here is my code:

```
TablePlot <- table(data_pre$NamePlot,data_pre$Genius_Species)
MatrixSpPlot <- as.matrix(TablePlot)
DFSpEV <- data.frame(data_pre[,c(9,11,12,13,14,15)])
DFSpEV <- aggregate(x = DFSpEV[,c(2,3,4,5,6)], by = list(DFSpEV$Genius_Species), FUN = mean, na.rm = T)
colnames(DFSpEV) <- c("Genius_Species","Soil_humidity","Soil_pH","Soil_nutrients","Light","Temperature")
functcomp(DFSpEV,MatrixSpPlot,CWM.type = c("dom"), bin.num = NULL)
```

In this code, I created a species presence/absence matrix for each site (MatrixSpPlot), and then I created a dataframe DFSpEV containing all species and their ecological indicator values (temperature, light, pH, soil nutrients and soil humidity), and I aggregated repeating species.

I don't understand this error, I tried to verify my data, the species are in the same order and are identical between my matrix and my data frame. What I have doubts about is the way I've created my matrix.

Can you help me please? Thank you so much!
Eléa

Comment: My answer is a formalization of steps I'd recommend, even though you say you checked them. The final note about spelling and case-sens is important, you might not see it easily but the expressions in the answer should help figure out which one(s) is/are different. If this still does not help resolve it for you, I suggest you make your question more _reproducible_ by adding sample data, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for discussions on using `dput` to add unambiguous sample data to your question. Thanks, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/cran/FD/blob/master/R/functcomp.R) for that function, specifically at

```r
s.x <- dim(x)[1]
s.a <- dim(a)[2]
if (s.x != s.a) stop("Different number of species in 'x' and 'a'.","\n")
if (any(x.n != a.n) ) stop("Species labels in 'x' and 'a' need to be identical and ordered alphabetically (or simply in the same order).","\n")
```

my guess is that your row names of `x` and column names of `a` must not only contain all the same names, but also be in the same order.

Some possible checks to resolve your issue, where names in one that are not in the other will either need to be removed from the one or added (if data can be found) in the other.

```r
rownames(DFSpEV) # should be not-empty
colnames(a) # same

# this shows rows in `a` that are not present in `x`
setdiff(rownames(DFSpEV), colnames(MatrixSpPlot))
# ditto, in reverse
setdiff(colnames(MatrixSpPlot), rownames(DFSpEV))
```

If the two `setdiff`s are empty, then you have them all, and this next command is likely failing in at least two locations:

```r
rownames(DFSpEV) == colnames(MatrixSpPlot)
```

One way that should resolve this is to make sure we use only those rownames/column-names that are present in both, and use the same order for both arguments:

```r
nms <- intersect(rownames(DFSpEV), colnames(MatrixSpPlot))
functcomp(DFSpEV[nms,], MatrixSpPlot[,nms], CWM.type = c("dom"), bin.num = NULL)
```

Using `nms` here has the effect of removing species that are in one and not the other, and ensuring all remaining species are in the same order.

Another thing to consider: spelling and capitalization. The strict test of `!=` does not tolerate change in order, spelling, upper/lower-case, and even (I have no idea about your data) locale/unicode/UTF differences.